# SSH into Pi Zero W over its WiFI when no local network is present?

Tags: networking, wifi, ssh, raspbian-buster, raspbian-lite

I'm running Raspberry Pi OS Lite on a Pi Zero W. Currently I can SSH into it through my WiFi internet. But what if I'm out in the field with no internet? How can I configure the Pi to become a WiFi hotspot that I can now SSH into?

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/configuration.html#setting-up-a-routed-wireless-access-point

Comment: I was hoping for a step-by-step guide. Is this a good one? https://www.raspberryconnect.com/projects/65-raspberrypi-hotspot-accesspoints/158-raspberry-pi-auto-wifi-hotspot-switch-direct-connection

Comment: The link I posted is a step by step guide!

Comment: Ahh, looks like it's the same setup procedure. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These setup guides are what I was looking for:

https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/configuration.html#setting-up-a-routed-wireless-access-point

https://www.raspberryconnect.com/projects/65-raspberrypi-hotspot-accesspoints/158-raspberry-pi-auto-wifi-hotspot-switch-direct-connection